Adding print and export csv buttons to dash app with python and js
I am building out a dash app and have attempted to include print and export csv buttons to the app using python and js.
I don't receive any traceback(s) or any indication there is an issue with the code, but the buttons create no effect when clicked. I have unsuccessfully solved this issue with the below code, and I am unsure how to remedy the situation. Added a few notes below to assist w/understanding context. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!
################# These are the libraries I have imported. #################
from dash import Dash, html, dash_table, dcc, callback, callback_context, Output, Input, State
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
            # This is indented due to its location in overall program.
            # Print/save button(s) layout.
            html.Button('Export .csv', id = 'save-btn', 
                style = {'display':'inline', 'fontSize': 14, 'color':colors['text'], 
                'backgroundColor': '#3385ff', 'border':'2px solid black', 
                'margin':'4px', 'borderRadius':0}), 
                
            html.Button('Print PDF', id='print-btn', n_clicks=0, 
                style = {'display':'inline', 'fontSize': 14, 'color':colors['text'], 
                'backgroundColor': '#3385ff', 'border':'2px solid black', 
                'margin':'4px', 'borderRadius':0}), 
            
            dcc.ConfirmDialog(
                id='confirm',
                message='Do you want to print?',
            ), 

################# Included callbacks below. #################

# Save callback
@callback(
    Output('save-button', 'n_clicks'),
    Input('save-button', 'n_clicks'),
    State('table', 'data')
)

def save_data(n_clicks, rows):
    if n_clicks is not None and n_clicks > 0:
        with open('data.csv', 'w', newline = '') as f:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames = rows[0].keys())
            writer.writeheader()
            writer.writerows(rows)
    return n_clicks

# Print callback
@callback(
    Output('print-button', 'n_clicks'),
    Input('confirm', 'submit_n_clicks')
)

def print_data(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks is not None and n_clicks > 0:
        print_function = """
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.print();
            </script>
            """
        return dcc.Markdown(print_function, dangerously_allow_html = True)
    return n_clicks

